# Showing encrypted images on JLabel

Tags: java, linux, image, swing, jlabel

My application encrypts some images; it also should display them (As a list by `JTable`).
What is the best way to display encrypted images in `JLabel` for protecting them from being copied by user from filesystem?

- Decrypting them in `/tmp/` directory and deleting each after showed in `JLabel`?
- Holding them in memory and make `Image` object from bytes in memory? 
  Anything else?

application will run on linux.

Edit: The displayed image is just a thumbnail, so screen capture is not a problem; my problem is when I decrypt file for creating thumbnail, the user shouldn't copy that.

Comment: You want to display an _encrypted_ image?  So it's encrypted on disk and decrypted for display in the application?

Comment: @DavidGrant: it is encrypted on disk and application can decrypt it.

Comment: And what's stopping the user from capturing the screen (eg: print screen) once your application decrypts and displays it?

Comment: This is ludicrous.  If the app. is not not displaying the full-size image and you don't mind the thumb-nail being copied, only distribute the thumb-nail (unencrypted) in the first place!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to decrypt your file directly in a byte buffer 
'byte[]' and then use that data in an imageicon : [imageicon constructor with byte buffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28byte%5b%5d%29)

decrypting in a temp file will allow the user to find those temporary files decrypted, which is not wat you want I suppose

Comment: Does not stop the 'print-screen approach' to image theft.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: No! the displayed image is just a thumbnail! so let him capture it; My problem is when I decrypt file for creating thumbnail he shouldn't copy that;